# Full Text Justification (Legal Documents)

Tags: asp.net, text, rdlc, text-justify

I understand that asp.net does not have built in support to make text fully justified like Microsoft Word (left and right justified). However, in googling this I have seen numerous different users posting possible solutions, but I have yet to find anything that actually works. Does anyone know how to accomplish this either with custom plug-ins or anything?

I am creating rdlc reports that my web app can generate based on entered data. So I will have text boxes that are numerous paragraphs and there is no way of knowing how many characters will be one a line (numerous placeholders of text added to generated report). Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Where will this text reside? Within a report?

Comment: Yes, I need the justified text on reports that are saved as PDF or Word documents. I am not worried about data input. I am creating RDLC files in visual studio that my web application generates downloadable reports. The text box control within visual studio does not support full text justification.

Comment: Again, to be clear for all readers: you're talking about the text box within the RDLC report, not a text box on a web form, right?

Comment: Correct, just for downloadable RDLC reports.